Display the all the details of Resident after clicking the view button using ASP.NET Core
Manage.cshtml
<table class="display table" id="ManageResident" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Resident ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var resident in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@resident.ResidentID</td>
                <td>@resident.FirstName</td>
                <td>@resident.MiddleName</td>
                <td>@resident.LastName</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#residentModal" data-resident='@Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(resident))'>
                        View
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>

resident.js
$('#residentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var resident = button.data('resident');

    console.log('Resident data:', resident); // Log the entire resident object to console

    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#modalResidentID').text(resident.residentID);
    modal.find('#modalFirstName').text(resident.firstName);
    modal.find('#modalMiddleName').text(resident.middleName);
    modal.find('#modalLastName').text(resident.lastName);
    modal.find('#modalBirthdate').text(resident.birthdate);
    modal.find('#modalAge').text(resident.age);
    modal.find('#modalEmail').text(resident.email);
    modal.find('#modalCreationDate').text(resident.creationDate);
    modal.find('#modalModifiedBy').text(resident.modifiedBy);
    modal.find('#modalModifiedDate').text(resident.modifiedDate);

    // Check if addresses are defined and not empty
    if (resident.addresses && resident.addresses.length > 0) {
        var addresses = resident.addresses;
        var addressList = modal.find('#modalAddresses').empty();
        addresses.forEach(function (address) {
            addressList.append('<li>' + address.street + ', ' + address.city + ', ' + address.state + ', ' + address.zipCode + '</li>');
        });
    } else {
        modal.find('#modalAddresses').html('<li>No addresses found.</li>');
    }

    // Check if contacts are defined and not empty
    if (resident.contacts && resident.contacts.length > 0) {
        var contacts = resident.contacts;
        var contactList = modal.find('#modalContacts').empty();
        contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
            contactList.append('<li>' + contact.contactType + ': ' + contact.contactValue + '</li>');
        });
    } else {
        modal.find('#modalContacts').html('<li>No contacts found.</li>');
    }
});

ResidentController.cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Manage()
{
    var residents = await _context.WMS_Resident
                        .Include(r => r.Addresses)
                        .Include(r => r.Contacts)
                        .ToListAsync();

    var residentViewModels = residents.Select(r => new ResidentViewModel
    {
        ResidentID = r.ResidentID,
        FirstName = r.FirstName,
        MiddleName = r.MiddleName,
        LastName = r.LastName,
        Birthdate = r.Birthdate,
        Age = r.Age,
        Email = r.Email,
        CreationDate = r.CreationDate,
        ModifiedBy = r.ModifiedBy,
        ModifiedDate = r.ModifiedDate,
        Addresses = r.Addresses.Select(a => new AddressViewModel
        {
            AddressID = a.AddressID,
            ResidentID = a.ResidentID,
            AddressType = a.AddressType,
            HouseNumber = a.HouseNumber,
            Street = a.Street,
            Barangay = a.Barangay,
            CreationDate = a.CreationDate,
            ModifiedBy = a.ModifiedBy,
            ModifiedDate = a.ModifiedDate
        }).ToList(),
        Contacts = r.Contacts.Select(c => new ContactViewModel
        {
            ContactID  = c.ContactID,
            ResidentID = c.ResidentID,
            ContactType = c.ContactType,
            ContactNumber = c.ContactNumber,
            CreationDate = c.CreationDate,
            ModifiedBy = c.ModifiedBy,
            ModifiedDate = c.ModifiedDate
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();

    return View(residentViewModels);
}

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div class="modal fade" id="residentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="residentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="residentModalLabel">Resident Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p><strong>Resident ID:</strong> <span id="modalResidentID"></span></p>
                <p><strong>First Name:</strong> <span id="modalFirstName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Middle Name:</strong> <span id="modalMiddleName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Last Name:</strong> <span id="modalLastName"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Birthdate:</strong> <span id="modalBirthdate"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Age:</strong> <span id="modalAge"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Email:</strong> <span id="modalEmail"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Creation Date:</strong> <span id="modalCreationDate"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Modified By:</strong> <span id="modalModifiedBy"></span></p>
                <p><strong>Modified Date:</strong> <span id="modalModifiedDate"></span></p>
                <h5>Addresses</h5>
                <ul id="modalAddresses"></ul>
                <h5>Contacts</h5>
                <ul id="modalContacts"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



In this scenario Manage.cshtml display all the resident but in limited fields but the resident wants to view all the information just clicking the view button it displays all the details of resident via modal.
But I encountered an issue once I clicked the view button of specific resident the modal information is NULL
Can anyone help me with this issue

You’re using wrong properties. The object has Age, you’re using age and so on

I used your codes and test in my side, the ViewModel is created by myself based on your code snippet.

Just like what you can see in the screenshot, using codes below will only display the age property correctly , and other properties are not. That's because the resident object printed in the console window matched the properties defining in ViewModel which is PascalCase but in your js you used camelCase. They didn't match with each other and cause the issue.
 var modal = $(this);
 console.info(resident);
 modal.find('#modalResidentID').text(resident.residentID);
 modal.find('#modalFirstName').text(resident.firstName);
 modal.find('#modalMiddleName').text(resident.middleName);
 modal.find('#modalLastName').text(resident.lastName);
 // modal.find('#modalBirthdate').text(resident.birthdate);
 modal.find('#modalAge').text(resident.age);
 modal.find('#modalEmail').text(resident.email);

So that what @Sami Kuhmonen said is correct, the issue is due to using the incorrect property name. Changing the js code to use codes like .text(resident.ResidentID) instead of residentID which matched the definition in the ViewModel will fix the issue. Please check your view to double confirm it.
